# Toggle Class not Working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a button to change the color of another button when user clicks on it. But, due to some unknown reasons it's not working. Please, help me out here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Gallery</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary">Click me!</p>
        <p id="btn2" class="btn btn-default">Change color!</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var main = function() {
            $("#btn2".click(function() {
                $("#btn1").toggleClass(".btn-primary");
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(main);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: replace the main-function with this: var main = function() {
            $("#btn2").click(function() {
                $("#btn1").toggleClass(function(){
                    return "btn-primary";
                });
            });
        }    You can pass a function to the toggleClass-method.

Answer (score 3):

do not put "." in front of the class name (as you would do in selector):

```
$("#btn1").toggleClass("btn-primary");
```

Comment: It is still not working. I've changed it to:
$("#btn1").toggleClass('btn-primary');

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$("#btn2".click(function() {
```

Should be:

```
$("#btn2").click(function() {
```

Notice the closing parenthesis after your "#btn2" selector.

As others have pointed out, you also need to remove the period from the start of the class name being toggled. You need to check your console for errors.

Comment: there is still a "." in the class pram

Answer (score 1):

Should look like this.

```
$("#btn2").click(function() {
    $("#btn1").toggleClass("btn-primary");
});
```

Comment: So the difference in your code is removing the period before btn-primary?

Comment: Yes and the missing ")" in the selector